# how to add plugin in aws-sam template.yaml file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-serverless, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

is there any way to add custom plugin in aws-sam template.yaml file like Serverless.yml file for eg:

```
plugins:
  - plugin-1
  - plugin-2

custom:
  abc:
   accountId: "************"
```

Comment: I want to implement 
https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/plugins/ this feature in aws-sam

Answer (score 1):

No, not exactly. However, a SAM template is just a untransformed Cloudformation template. So depending on what precisely you want to achieve, creating a CFN [Macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) might be an option.